# Magento New Products Block

Tags: magento

I would like some help on how to a block or the right sidebar displaying the new products added to the store.

Answer (score 1):

To add new products to a CMS page (Home, Contact, etc) use the block code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

From http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page

For sidebar please refer

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/10331/

You'll have to set the reference pointer to be Right or Left

Answer (score 0):

Create widget for the sidebar with new product block and set the template where to show that widget.

1. Go to **CMS->Widgets** section from admin menu.
2. Than select type as **CMS Static Block** and theme, set **Widget Instance Title** and order and click **Add Layout Update** button.
3. Select **All Pages** from **Display On** section and than select **Block Reference** as Right Column.
4. Now select Block from **Widget Options** menu and save.
5. Refresh cache and now the **New Product Block** visible on right sidebar.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You can do it without changing the html files.